# How does phrase searching and phrase search with ~N interact with quote_field_suffix in a simple query string query?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, given:

```
PUT index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "english_exact": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "body": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english",
        "fields": {
          "exact": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "english_exact"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT index/_doc/1
{
  "body": "Ski resorts"
}

PUT index/_doc/1
{
  "body": "Ski house resorts"
}
```

What happens with the following queries?

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [ "body" ],
      "quote_field_suffix": ".exact",
      "query": "\"ski resort\""
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [ "body" ],
      "quote_field_suffix": ".exact",
      "query": "\"ski resort\"~2"
    }
  }
}
```

Will the ".exact" extend to the entire phrase, so in this case the first query would get no results?

How could you do a phrase search that is not exact when using quote "quote_field_suffix": ".exact"?

Answer (score 1):

> Will the ".exact" extend to the entire phrase, so in this case the first query would get no results?

Yes, Your understanding is correct.

> Documentation says, Suffix appended to quoted text in the query string.

So, it will search for exact match for `ski resort`. It is not there so it will return empty result.

> How could you do a phrase search that is not exact when using quote "quote_field_suffix": ".exact"?

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [ "body" ],
      "quote_field_suffix": ".exact",
      "query": "ski resort~2"
    }
  }
}
```

It is not exact because it brings `ski resorts` also.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!